# Can't add a new field to the body of the request

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul

I have a small problem. In a PreFilter I get the currentContext and I'm able to read the body value like that:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
context.getRequest().getParameter("key-example")).
```

All good for that, but I want to add a new field to the request body and I'm not able to do that, because there isn't such a method that can help me. How can I perform this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many ways to achieve this. Either using **AOP** to modify the argument before the method is called or **Servlet Filter**.

For the case of Filter, it requires you to create a request wrapper class which extends from `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and override the `getInputStream` method to return the request body as your desire.

An alternative way which is way simpler to use **request attribute** instead by
`request.setAttribute("customAttribute", value)`